# SQL Server stored procedure returns temporary records that doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a timesheet table records stored as follows in `DetailsTbl`:

```
ID   |  Day        | hours
----------------------------
 1   | 14/feb/14   |   8
 1   | 15/feb/14   |   8
```

And table called `PAssign` as follows:

```
 ID | from      | to
----------------------------------
 1  | 14/feb/14 | 17/feb/14
```

By executing the stored procedure, output should show:

```
ID | from      | to        | day       | Hours
------------------------------------------------
 1 | 14/feb/14 | 17/feb/14 | 14/feb/14 |  8
 1 | 14/feb/14 | 17/feb/14 | 15/feb/14 |  8
 1 | 14/feb/14 | 17/feb/14 | 16/feb/14 |  0
 1 | 14/feb/14 | 17/feb/14 | 17/feb/14 |  0
```

Only the null values where **day** between the **from** /  **to** should be set to default which is '**0**'

help appreciated

Comment: What is your question?   What is the stored proc doing?

Comment: the storedproc should show the 3rd table, anyway thanks for cooperation, i got the answer i needed from Mr. mellamokb

Answer (score 0):

Taking a range and exploding it into multiple records can be done with a [recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or a [Numbers table](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=NumbersTable).  Here is an example using a recursive CTE:

```
;with cte as (
  select [id], [from], [to], [from] as day from PAssign
  union all
  select [id], [from], [to], [day]+1 from cte
  where [day] < [to]
)
select
  cte.id, cte.[from], cte.[to], cte.[day],
  coalesce(d.hours, 0) as hours
from cte
left join DetailsTbl d on cte.id = d.id and cte.day = d.day
```

Results ([**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0ed3/3))

```
| ID |                            FROM |                              TO |                             DAY | HOURS |
|----|---------------------------------|---------------------------------|---------------------------------|-------|
|  1 | February, 14 2014 00:00:00+0000 | February, 17 2014 00:00:00+0000 | February, 14 2014 00:00:00+0000 |     8 |
|  1 | February, 14 2014 00:00:00+0000 | February, 17 2014 00:00:00+0000 | February, 15 2014 00:00:00+0000 |     8 |
|  1 | February, 14 2014 00:00:00+0000 | February, 17 2014 00:00:00+0000 | February, 16 2014 00:00:00+0000 |     0 |
|  1 | February, 14 2014 00:00:00+0000 | February, 17 2014 00:00:00+0000 | February, 17 2014 00:00:00+0000 |     0 |
```

Turning this into a stored procedure should be pretty easy.  Also note that a Recursive CTE makes use of one level of recursion per record generated, so you'll need to set the [maximum recursion level](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/juggling_with_sql/2011/06/04/maximum-recursion-possible-with-cte-in-sql-server-2005-2008/) as appropriate.

Comment: Dear, thanks for the quick reply, how does this works with multiple ID's?